# Using log4net Context Properties has negative impact on performance?

Tags: c#, performance, logging, log4net

Posting this to see if anyone has had a similar experience and if there's any known workarounds?

**Update**: log4net team has acknowledged this as an issue , see link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-429

I've found that if I use a pattern that uses a custom property, logging will be 3-5 times slower. To illustrate this I have setup an example project that logs 10000 times with 2 different loggers and appenders. 1 of them has a custom string property.

Typical output:

> Elapsed Time (No property): 800ms,  Elapsed Time (With property) 2400ms

**Three times slower when logging with a context property**

After doing some decompiling I *think* that as soon as you output a parameter it will end up touching the current user name in the process, an expensive operation. I'm not sure, but I think that's whats going on.

To reproduce it, create a console application and use the following app.config and main.cs

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>    
    <appender name="NoPropertyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="PropertyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{customProperty}- %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="NoProperty">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="NoPropertyAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="HasProperty">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="PropertyAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Main.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        //private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Arrange
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            GlobalContext.Properties["customProperty"] = "Test";
            var nrOfRepetitions = 10000;

            var noPropertyLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("NoProperty");
            var propertyLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("HasProperty");

            var noPropertyStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            var propertyStopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            noPropertyStopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                noPropertyLogger.Info("Logging without custom Parameter.");

            }
            noPropertyStopwatch.Stop();


            propertyStopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < nrOfRepetitions; i++)
            {
                propertyLogger.Info("Logging with custom parameter");
            }
            propertyStopwatch.Stop();

            noPropertyLogger.Info(string.Format("Elapsed time: (No property) {0}", noPropertyStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            propertyLogger.Info(string.Format("Elapsed time: (With property) {0}", propertyStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```